# Sending SQS messages via SoupUI

Tags: soapui, aws

I'm using `SQS` in local, and I try to send a query using SoapUI:

My Query look like this :

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4576 
sqs send-message 
--queue-url http://localhost:4576/queue/eventQueue.fifo 
--message-group-id test 
--message-body "{\"action\":\"UPSERT\",\"someCode\":\"7895\",\"updateTime\":\"1575454982307\"}"
```

I tried to simulate to send my query in SoupUI, but I don't have any clue to do this, usually I use aws CLI to do this, but my requirement now is changes.

Any one can advice me how can I use this in SoapUI please.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by converting this query to an API request based on this article on AWS [Making Query API Requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-making-api-requests.html)

My query now look like this :

```
http://localhost:4576?
Action=SendMessage&
QueueName=eventQueue.fifo
&MessageGroupId=test
&MessageBody={"action":"UPSERT","someCode":"7896","updateTime":"1575454982307"}
```

[image: SoapUI SQS]